# SceneKit's "allowsCameraControl" equivalent in RealityKit

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

In SceneKit SDK to allow controlling a camera movement you need to set a parameter called `.allowsCameraControl` to **true**.

```
var scnView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
```

What parameter for controlling a camera (dolly in, dolly out) is used in RealityKit?

```
var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
// ???
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment RealityKit 2.0 has no SceneKit's equivalent called `.allowsCameraControl`  for moving and rotating virtual camera. Cupertino engineers consider that there's no need to have such a control because RealityKit is rather AR-sentric framework than VR-sentric one.

For further details, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516286/realitykit-as-a-framework-to-build-3d-nonar-apps/71516339#71516339).

Comment: This is getting a bit annoying... the divide between RK and SK is really becoming a problem, they overlap, but each is missing lots.

Comment: I agree @danm, the best choice is to use just one SDK, not both. I prefer RealityKit, cause it has more modern features.

Comment: @AndyJazz, without something like .allowsCameraControl, It is impossible to use RealityKit for any nonAr use case.... Is there any workaround? Seems like apple abandoned Scenekit, but has no 3D framework to replace

Comment: Hi @ManeManero, could you publish it as a question (not comment)?

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516286/realitykit-as-a-framework-to-build-3d-nonar-apps

Comment: Hi @Kurt, I've updated my answer.