# RealityKit's `.allowsCameraControl` tool for building `nonAR` apps

Tags: swift, scenekit, virtual-reality, realitykit

RealityKit has an option for `.nonAR` camera, but lacks fundamental options to build 3D nonAR apps, like camera control (`.allowsCameraComtrol`).

Is it viable to use RealityKit a replacement for SceneKit (which hasn't been updated for the past years and will likely be desecrated soon)?

Comment: I think you probably meant [deprecated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprecate#Verb) rather than [desecrated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desecrate#Verb) (Although if you were a big enough fan of SceneKit, I guess you might consider it desecration to remove it )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `.allowsCameraControl` equivalent

Apple has been preparing a replacement for SceneKit, and it's definitely a Reality family – RealityKit, RealityFoundation, Reality Composer (iOS/macOS), Reality Composer Pro (rather for visionOS), Reality Converter, ARQuickLook, etc. Using RealityKit 2.0, you can create both AR and VR apps. As a tool for prototyping 3D scenes, you need to use Reality Composer. And even despite the lack of such an important feature as `.allowsCameraControl`, you are now able to make VR apps using RealityKit.

#### Workaround

Nonetheless, use my code as a ***starting point*** to create your own camera control for VR in RealityKit:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let buildings = try! Experience.loadScene()
    let camera = PerspectiveCamera()
    var current_X_Angle: Float = 0.0
    var current_Y_Angle: Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.environment.background = .color(.systemCyan)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(buildings)
        self.camera.position.z = 1
        buildings.children[0].addChild(self.camera)
        self.gestureRecognizer()
    }
    func gestureRecognizer() {
        for gestureRecognizer in [UIPanGestureRecognizer.self,
                                  UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self] {
            if gestureRecognizer == UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self {
                let r = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                               action: #selector(allowCameraControl_01))
                arView.addGestureRecognizer(r)
            }
            if gestureRecognizer == UIPanGestureRecognizer.self {
                let r = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                               action: #selector(allowCameraControl_02))
                arView.addGestureRecognizer(r)
            }
        }
    }
    @objc func allowCameraControl_01(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
            case .changed, .ended:
                self.camera.position.z *= 1 / Float(recognizer.scale)
                recognizer.scale = 1.0
            default: break
        }
    }
    @objc func allowCameraControl_02(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
            case .changed, .ended:
                let translate = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view)
                let angle_X = Float(translate.y / 300) * .pi / 180.0
                let angle_Y = Float(translate.x / 100) * .pi / 180.0
                self.current_X_Angle += angle_X
                self.current_Y_Angle += angle_Y                
                camera.setOrientation(Transform(pitch: current_X_Angle,
                                                  yaw: current_Y_Angle,
                                                 roll: .zero).rotation,
                                      relativeTo: buildings.anchor)
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here you can find [SwiftUI version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596996/how-do-i-use-swiftui-gestures-to-control-a-usdz-model-in-arview).

[image]

#### visionOS Xcode Simulator

In Xcode 15's visionOS simulator, there are `Pan`, `Orbit` and `Dolly` UI buttons, available in lower right corner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, you are the Reality man! 

Comment: so... still no native camera control on latest RealityKit Xcode 15.2?

Comment: And now Reality Composer has been removed from Xcode…

Comment: @ViktorSec, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748779/can-we-use-reality-composer-pro-for-arview/77512647#77512647), please.

Comment: @AndyJazz thanks for the workaround, but I'm not sure if it makes sense to start depending on something that needs to be smuggled in such a way to the dev tools. The silent removal of the app doesn't inspire much confidence.

BTW: Thank you for your answers on all of the topics in this domain. I keep running into your name and your posts seem very useful :)