# How to move the camera around with gestures in RealityKit?

Tags: realitykit

In SceneKit when you have a scene you can use gestures to move around the 3D space. How can you do this in RealityKit (using non-AR), or is it not possible? I am using SwiftUI as well.

Comment: Read this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516286/realitykit-as-a-framework-to-build-3d-nonar-apps/71516339#71516339