# How do I use SwiftUI gestures to control a camera in ARView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I have an ARView contained in a UIViewRepresentable. A USDZ model is loaded. All of this displays in SwiftUI view. The ARView is `.nonAR`.

I want a DragGesture and a PinchGesture in SwiftUI to control the camera position.

Is this possible? ARView seems not to have a direct equivalent of `allowsCameraControl` like you get in SceneKit.

Comment: Is this for visionOS or ios/iPadOS?

Comment: Hey @Stoic, ARView (unlike RealityView) is definitely for iOS/macOS.

Comment: LOL @stoic I _wish_ it was for visionOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NonAR Camera Control

To control RealityKit's `nonAR` camera position with SwiftUI gestures, use following code. I used a SwiftUI's pinch gesture (MagnifyGesture struct) to simulate `dolly in` and `dolly out` camera behavior. You can [tweak the dolly formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516286/realitykits-allowscameracontrol-tool-for-building-nonar-apps/71516339#71516339) until you get the perfect camera movement.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

class GestureDrivenCamera: Entity, HasPerspectiveCamera {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.position.z = 4.0
        self.camera.fieldOfViewInDegrees = 50.0
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    @GestureState var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 0.001
    @State var state: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State var camera = GestureDrivenCamera()
    
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, camera: $camera)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .gesture(
                MagnifyGesture()
                    .updating($magnifyBy) { (value, _, _) in
                        Task {
                            camera.position.z = Float(state + value.magnification)
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        state = value.magnification
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var camera: GestureDrivenCamera
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh)

        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.children.append(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        anchor.addChild(camera)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```